# JSLint complains when I try to update a property with itself

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to update my jquery selectors, but JSLint complains when I try to do so.

I'm also using a namespace to make my code more organized.

```
FOO.SELECTORS = {
    Element: $('foo'),
    Element2: $('bar')
};

FOO.UPDATE = {
    FOO.SELECTORS = FOO.SELECTORS
};
```

This makes JSLint complain that `FOO.SELECTORS = FOO.SELECTORS` is a weird assignment. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do variable assignment inside of an object. This is incorrect.

If you are going to do this, (not entirely sure what you're doing), you should write it like this:

```
FOO.UPDATE = {
    'FOO.SELECTORS': FOO.SELECTORS
}
```

Again, really not exactly sure what you're trying to do?

Comment: Oh my god, I was really tired yesterday. It works perfectly now, thanks!

Comment: Haha, no problem. I've actually seen that a lot so you're not alone.